# MySQL query with GROUP BY, SUM, MAX and subquery

Tags: mysql

I have the following tabel structure:

```
Id  Num1  Num2  Type  Num3
1    2     2     1     4
1    3     1     2     5
1    1     1     3     2
2    2     1     1     3
2    0     1     2     2
2    4     3     3     6
```

I need a query with group by 'Id', sum of 'Num1', sum of 'Num2', max of 'Num3' and the 'Type' related to the MAX of 'Num3'.
So, the desired output is:

```
Id  Sum(Num1)  Sum(Num2)  type  Max(Num3)
1       6          4       2       5   
2       6          4       3       6
```

Without this related 'Type' the query below works fine:

```
SELECT
 Id,
 SUM(Num1),
 SUM(Num2),
 MAX(Num3)
GROUP BY
 Id
```

I tried different methods of subquery but can't make it work yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is a bit of a spin on the greatest value per group problem.  In this case, we can use a subquery to find the max `Num3` value for each `Id`.  But, in the same subquery we also compute the sum aggregates.

```
SELECT
    t1.Id,
    t2.s1,
    t2.s2,
    t1.Type,
    t1.Num3
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Id, SUM(Num1) AS s1, SUM(Num2) AS s2, MAX(Num3) AS m3
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY Id
) t2
    ON t1.Id = t2.Id AND t1.Num3 = t2.m3;
```

As a hat tip to MySQL 8+, and to ward off evil spirits, we can also write a query using analytic functions:

```
SELECT Id, s1, s2, Type, Num3
FROM
(
    SELECT
        Id,
        SUM(Num1) OVER (PARTITION BY Id) s1,
        SUM(Num2) OVER (PARTITION BY Id) s2,
        Type,
        Num3,
        MAX(Num3) OVER (PARTITION BY Id) m3
    FROM yourTable
) t
WHERE Num3 = m3;
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! thank you! My mistake was doing in the oposite order the outer and inner query.